# fetching data from response.body gives null uisng retrofit in android

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, response, jsonresponse

Hey i am trying to fetch data from my api using retrofit with node.js backend and then set it to Textview. I am able connect to api successfully but it gives me problems when i try to set text to textview. I have a function **getCompanyname** in my pojo **when i try to use this function to set text it shows nothing in the textview and when i tried it in Toast message is gives null as a message** so i fount that my method has null value but i could not able to find the problem. Below is required code

1) **code of RequestInterface**

```
public interface RetrofitInterface {

@POST("logins")
Call<ServerResponse> operation(@Body ServerRequest request);
@GET("getbusinessprofile/{username}")
Call<CompanyInfo> getCompanydetails(@Path("username")String username);
}
```

2) **dashboard frag**

```
public void getCompanyData(String username){

           Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                              .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
                              .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                              .build();

    RetrofitInterface requestInterface = retrofit.create(RetrofitInterface.class);
    Call<CompanyInfo> callResponse = requestInterface.getCompanydetails(username);

    callResponse.enqueue(new Callback<CompanyInfo>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<CompanyInfo> call, Response<CompanyInfo> response) {

           CompanyInfo info=response.body();
           comp_text.setText(info.getCompanyname());
           mail_text.setText(info.getEmail());
           gst_text.setText(info.getGstNo());
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Company name-> "+info.getCompanyname(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
```

My getCompanyname, getGST, getEmail all of these are null

Here's my json response on console

```
{"companyname":"hitouch","email":"a@b.com","gst_no":"12354"}
```

3) **CompanyInfo.java

```
public class CompanyInfo {

@SerializedName("companyname")
@Expose
private String companyname;
@SerializedName("email")
@Expose
private String email;
@SerializedName("gst_no")
@Expose
private String gstNo;

public String getCompanyname() {
    return companyname;
}

public void setCompanyname(String companyname) {
    this.companyname = companyname;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getGstNo() {
    return gstNo;
}

public void setGstNo(String gstNo) {
    this.gstNo = gstNo;
}

}
```

Please suggest me something and if you want i can post my backend code of node.js

THANKS !!

Edit

[image: Debug response]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182270/discussion-between-aolphn-and-prashant-singh).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the response is like this

```
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "body": { "companyname": "hitouch", "email": "a@b.com", "gst_no": "12354" }
}
```

you have to use pojo like this

```
public class CompanyInfoResponse {
    @SerializedName("statusCode")
    int statusCode;

    @SerializedName("headers")
    Map<String, String> headers;        

    @SerializedName("body")
    CompanyInfo companyInfo;
}
```

The change it to

```
@GET("getbusinessprofile/{username}")
Call<ApiResponse<CompanyInfo>> 
        getCompanydetails(@Path("username")String username);
```

To get Actual data

```
CompanyInfo companyInfo = response.body().getBody();
```

If you want to apply it to different type of Response like EmployeeInfo you can use a wrapper like this

```
public class ApiResponse<T> {
    private transient boolean isSuccess;

    @SerializedName("statusCode")
    private int statusCode;
    @SerializedName("headers")
    Map<String, String> headers;
    @SerializedName("body")
    private T body;

    @Nullable
    public int getStatusCode() {
        return statusCode;
    }

    @Nullable
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
        return headers;
    }

    @Nullable
    public T getBody() {
        return body;
    }
}
```

Then declare like this

```
@GET("getbusinessprofile/{username}")
Call<ApiResponse<CompanyInfo>> getCompanydetails(@Path("username")String username);

@GET("getbusinessprofile/{username}")
Call<ApiResponse<EmployeeInfo>> getEmployeeDetails(@Path("username")String username);
```

To get Actual data

```
CompanyInfo companyInfo = response.body().getBody();
EmployeeInfo empInfo = response.body().getBody();
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182274/discussion-between-jaisel-rahman-and-prashant-singh).